# Sub-queries using XSB Prolog's C API (embedded)

Tags: c, prolog, xsb

I have a program (C++) that embeds XSB Prolog to use as a constraint solver.  I have already written code using the low-level C API to inject facts and run queries.  But I am getting stuck on a particular side-problem.

I would like to (for debugging purposes) run a query and then output each term that the query unifies with to a stream.  In order to ensure that the outputs are nice, I thought it would be nice to use the output of `string:term_to_atom/2` to generate the strings.

So, I'd like to put the query term in register 1, run `xsb_query()`, and then run `string:term_to_atom/2` on the results.  But running `string:term_to_atom/2` is a query itself, and you can't run `xsb_query()` when you are in the middle of a query.

I tried using `xsb_query_save()`, hoping that I could then do a sub-query, followed by `xsb_query_restore()`, but that doesn't appear to work.  The call to my sub-query still bombs out because there is already a query in progress.

I thought about saving a vector of variables created with `p2p_new()` that have been unified using `p2p_unify()` with `reg_term(1)`, but I have no idea how or when these terms might get garbage collected, as I see no way for XSB Prolog to know that my C program is using them.  (Unless I am supposed to call the undocumented `p2p_deref()` on them when I am done with them?)

Finally, I would like to do this in a single query (if possible) in order to avoid cluttering up the namespace with what would amount to a temporary rule.  But maybe I am trying too hard and I should be using another approach entirely.  Ideas?